# SQL Server Stored Procedure syntax error when adding several OR clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to select some products from products table using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2016 but when I am adding several or clause it gives me this syntax error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '100'.

here is the line of stored procedure that when I add it, it gives me the error. (without this line, it is ok):

```
@StoreId int = null,
//the code is quite verbose and I added storeid variable as a clarification here 
//and in the actual code it is defined in the proper line(not here) and the part 
//that is creating the error is the below part cause I have tested it and When I 
//remove it, it performs ok
IF @ShowUnavailable = 1
        set @sql = 
            'SELECT Distinct P.ProductId, P.BrandId, P.[' + @OrderIndex + ']  FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductStores PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId ' +
            'Where  PS.StoreId = @StoreId and (PS.Status  IN (' + @availabilityStatus + ') or (PS.StoreId != @StoreId and PS.Status IN(0,2))'
```

Comment: Your query ends with `or PS.AvailabilityRank <`. There is something missing at the end: `or PS.AvailabilityRank < ???`. Also have a look at `PS.StoreId = @StoreId` and `PS.StoreId != @StoreId`

Comment: no it was on purpose, when I remove it, I still get the error

Comment: Also check the `@StoreID` parts. `'PS.StoreId = ' + @StoreId + ' ... ' ` instead of `'PS.StoreId = @StoreId'`

Comment: @SebastianBrosch now it is giving me this error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT Distinct P.ProductId, P.BrandId, P.[OrderCount]  FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductStores PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId Where  PS.StoreId = ' to data type int.

Comment: What is the data type of @StoreID? It is better to add the variable data type in your post.

Comment: @GenWan I have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, If the variable is an integer, you need to convert it to varchar. Because @sql is a string.

2, Please clarify the data type of @availabilityStatus. I used '1,2' as the sample.

```
declare @StoreID int = 0
declare @OrderIndex int = 0
declare @availabilityStatus varchar(max) = '1,2'
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 
            'SELECT Distinct P.ProductId, P.BrandId, P.[' + cast(@OrderIndex as varchar(100)) + '] FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductStores PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId ' +
            'Where PS.StoreId = '+ cast(@StoreId as varchar(100))+ ' and (PS.Status  IN (' + @availabilityStatus + ') or (PS.StoreId != '+cast(@StoreId as varchar(100))+' and PS.Status IN(0,2))'

Print @sql
```

---

Test Result:
[DB <> Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9a675c24dfd796981ec870323fafd8b8)

Comment: @geekymano Did you use the recent one? I just updated. You can check the test result if the output is the query you want.

Comment: now it is executing but gives this error: INSERT INTO #ProductIds (ProductId, BrandId) SELECT ProductId, BrandId FROM (100)  and (P.Status = 1 or P.Status = 5) ) AS temp ORDER BY OrderCount DESC
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '100'.

Comment: @geekymano  As the error message said 'syntax error near 100', how can you select ... from (100)? If your table name is 100, please use brackets [100].

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems like `@OrderIndex` is of datatype `INT` and while string concatenation an Implicit conversion is happening creating the error. Try converting `@OrderIndex` as `cast (@OrderIndex as varchar)` to resolve the error `[Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ...to data type int.]

Edit: If above is not the case and error is coming not while code compilation but while executing the dynamic sql `@sql` string then explicitly convert int datatype to varchar for string concatenation as `cast (@StoreID as varchar)`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
'Where  PS.StoreId = **@StoreId** and (PS.Status  IN (' + @availabilityStatus + ') or (PS.StoreId != **@StoreId** and PS.Status IN(0,2))'
```

the way you have passed @StoreId is seems to be some thing wrong.

please use proper cast or conversion of nvarchar to int if needed.